# Do you need to "unwire" an anonymous function/lambda

Tags: c#, events, lambda, event-handling, anonymous-function

My understanding is that any event handlers wired up in C# need to be unwired as such.

```
Object myObject = new Object();
myObject.Event += EventHandler; //Wired
myObject.Event -= EventHandler; //Unwired
```

But do you  need to unwire the following code? and if so, how?

```
Object myObject = new Object();
myObject.Event += (object sender, EventArgs e) => { }; //Wired
myObject.Event -= ????? //Unwire? How?
```

**My assumption is no?**

Comment: Could you clarify what your understanding is - what do you mean by 'need to be' ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you need to (*) and you need to do it like this:

```
Object myObject = new Object();
EventHandler handler = (object sender, EventArgs e) => { };
myObject.Event += handler; //Wired
myObject.Event -= handler; //Unwired
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200424/event-fires-more-and-more-times/6200458#6200458) for an explanation.

**(*)**
You don't need to do it because of garbage collection. You need to do it, if you don't want the event to call your handler any more.

UPDATE:
To clarify a bit:
The only reason, why you want to unwire an event handler is that the object defining the event handler can be garbage collected.
Think about the following example:

- You have a class `PowerSource` with an event `BlackOut`.
- You have a class `LightBulb` that will be on, as long as there is power. It has a method `ConnectToPowerSource`. This method subscribes to the `BlackOut` event of the supplied `PowerSource`.
- You have a collection that contains the light bulbs

Now, simply removing a light bulb from the list will not make it get garbage collected, because the `PowerSource` is still holding a reference to the `LightBulb` instance in its `BlackOut` event. Only after unregistering the `LightBulb` from the `BlackOut` event will make the `LightBulb` get garbage collected.

Comment: +1 for **(*)**. Because you never **have** to unwire, you just either need or don't need to.

Comment: What do you mean by your `(*)` sentence? As long as the event handler exists it will keep all captured local variables from being collected. So you need to do it because of GC too(at least if the publisher of the event lives much longer than the consumer). But of course the most common reason for unwiring is that you don't want your eventhandler called anymore. (I'm not the downvoter)

Comment: What I mean is: If myObject is not needed anymore and all references are gone, it will be garbage collected, along with the anonymous methods assigned to its event handler. If myObject is still used, but you don't want your specific event handler not to be invoked anymore, you need to unwire it, which will then lead to garbage collection of it, if no reference to it is saved anymore. I guess, what I want to say is: You don't need to unwire it, for myObject to be collected. But that really has nothing to do with anonymous methods and is the case for all event handlers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you do have to. Because an event is a strong reference, your event handler will continue to be invoked.

You can remove it as follows:

```
EventHandler handler = (s,e) => { DoSomething(); }
myObject.Event += handler; 
myObject.Event -= handler;
```

Comment: You **do have to** if you **want the handler to stop being invoked**. If you don't care, you don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

```
Object myObject = new Object();
EventHandler h = (object sender, EventArgs e) => { }; //Wired
myObject.Event += h;
myObject.Event -= h;
```

Or, to unwire in the handler:

```
Object myObject = new Object();
EventHandler h = null; //need to declare h to use it in the following line
//compiler/resharper will complain about modified closure
h = (object sender, EventArgs e) => { myObject.Event-=h; };
myObject.Event += h;
```