# How Can I Remove Event?

Tags: c#, events

I am adding a event like that

```
Button button = new Button();

button.Click += (o,e) =>
{
//Somecode
};
```

How can Remove this event?

Comment: How do you add the event like that? That won't even compile.

Comment: It is missing the `+=`, but the rest is valid code, it's a lambda method.

Comment: Instead of removing the event add class member to act as sort of a "flag" - when raised, ignore the click.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291460/do-you-need-to-unwire-an-anonymous-function-lambda/6291482#6291482) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200424/event-fires-more-and-more-times/6200458#6200458). Essence: You need to save the anonymous method into a variable.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This may help;

```
        Button btn = new Button();
        this.Controls.Add(btn);
        btn.Click += (o, x) =>
        {
            Button b = o as Button;
            FieldInfo eventclick = typeof(Control).GetField("EventClick", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            object eventValue = eventclick.GetValue(b);
            PropertyInfo events = b.GetType().GetProperty("Events", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            EventHandlerList eventHandlerList = (EventHandlerList)events.GetValue(b, null);
            eventHandlerList .RemoveHandler(eventValue, eventHandlerList [eventValue]);
            MessageBox.Show("Test");
        };
```

Answer (score 7):

The correct syntax is

```
button.Click += (o, e) => {  /*code*/ };
```

You can't remove that, as it is an anomynous method (a lambda). If you want to be able to remove an event handler, you'll have to move the code to an extra method.

If you save the lambda as a delegate:

```
EventHandler<EventArgs> handler = (o, e) => {  //code };
```

You can add/remove it:

```
button.Click += handler;
button.Click -= handler;
```

However, I'd strongly advise against that. Use a named method instead.

Comment: +1, for "lambda way", was actually thinking how it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: you can't, you can only remove the handler of the event by `-=`. if you want to remove the handler then don't use anonymous methods. instead use a predefined method like:

```
button.Click += OnButtonClick;

private void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //some code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that if you store the delegate.

```
Button button=new Button();

EventHandler<...> handler=(o,e)=>
{
//Somecode
}

button.Click+=handler;
button.Click-=handler;
```

But I recommend using a named method instead. I see no gain in using a lambda here.

Comment: +1 Closest to what the OP is asking (bar his syntax error). It's not *required* to use a named method over an anonymous delegate, just *recommended*.