# Remove (-=) Form#FormClosed event added (+=) in derived class from class instance?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, event-handling, anonymous-delegates

I have a "MyForm" that derives from System.Windows.Form.Form.  MyForm handles the FormClosed event whose handler I set up in the constructor.  Is it possible for an instantiated MyForm object to successfully remove my MyClass#FormClosed handler using -=? I am using an anonymous method to wire my FormClosed event if that matters.

```
// In MyForm Constructor, this ALWAYS gets fired...
FormClosed += (_sender, _args) => { m_mutex.Dispose(); m_mutex = null; };

// In Instantiating Class
MyForm form = new MyForm();
form.FormClosed += (_sender, _args) => {  };

// I have also tried using "delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)" and neither worked.
```

Comment: Maybe provide a sample of your current subscription and un-subscription ...??? And, have you tried this yourself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event fires more and more times](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200424/event-fires-more-and-more-times)

Comment: @Abstract - I've tried with what I believed to be the proper anonymous signature, but it was not removed successfully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can remove it - but if you've used an anonymous function, it's slightly trickier.

Basically you'll *either* need to stop using an anonymous function (i.e. put the behaviour into a method) *or* you'll need to have a field to store the value of the delegate:

```
private EventHandler formClosedHandler;
...

// In constructor
formClosedHandler = (sender, args) => { ... };
FormClosed += formClosedHandler;

// Later...
FormClosed -= formClosedHandler;
formClosedHandler = null;
```

Personally I'd favour moving the logic into a method unless it's really tricky for some reason.

Comment: I feel rather pleased that this is the answer I was typing :)  Who would have thought I would be thinking like Jon Skeet?

Comment: I've become quite comfortable with this form: `formClosedHandler = (sender, args) => { ... };`. This makes handling un-subbing & cleanup very easy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can unsubscribe from any of the events, even in the `Disposed()` method.