# WinForms Form is never garbage collected due to reference from ServiceScope

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, async-await, garbage-collection

I have a WinForms Form(s) that is not always garbage collected. The form loads quite a bit of data and when it is not garbage collected, it can cause a significant memory leak. This is how I instantiate the form:

```cs
// RootForm.cs
private void CreateFormInScope<T>() where T : Form
{
  var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
  var form = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<T>();
  form.FormClosed += (_, _) => scope.Dispose();
  form.MdiParent = this;
  form.Show();
}
```

After failing to get anywhere with Visual Studio's diagnostic tools, I tried `dotnet dump`. I used `dumpheap -type [TYPENAME]` and then used `gcroot` on one of the addresses. Here's the end of the root shown:

> ```
> -> 00000170022A7598 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.CoreOptionsExtension
> -> 00000170022A1610 Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope
> -> 00000170022EA2C0 System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib]]
> -> 0000017002BBDD50 System.Object[]
> -> 00000170022EF580 FunctionScreens.ProductForm
> ```

OK, a scope is holding a reference to the ProductForm. The only scope that could have a reference to it is the child scope I created, right? But that child scope was a local variable, so it shouldn't be referenced by anything, let alone EF Core.

The leak does seem to occur more often if I close the window before `async` operations are complete, but I do catch all the exceptions in the event handlers to prevent them from propagating.

Any ideas why it is not being GCed or what I could do to track it down?

Comment: If I am right, the issue here, is the FormClosed event. Your Form (or any other object) will never be disposed, if there is still an event handler assigned. You need to make sure, there are no references assigned to an object to dispose it.

Comment: You might want to take a look at this answer to get you started https://stackoverflow.com/a/6666610/1068922

Comment: Which what lifestyle did you register your form?

Comment: The form and scope reference each other. Form references its scope through the `FormClosed` event. But that shouldn't make them rooted. When they both go out of scope, they will be cleaned up eventually. Please run `GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); GC.Collect();` before doing your dump to make sure that you aren't getting any false positives. If the forms are still in memory after that, either the form or the scope is referenced by something else, which is not detectable in your question. There are ways to analyze why objects are rooted, but I'm no expert on this.

Comment: The forms are using transient scope. The event handlers are not the problem as they would be GCed once `scope` is out of scope (I've updated the code to clarify the scope/context. This is working fine in most cases. I've also ensured that GC has been run. As for the object root, that's where I'm stuck. Per the example above, scope is somehow rooted in EF Core, but that doesn't make sense since `scope` is a local variable.